# Updating the url as per selected values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to parse the url as per the selection in the dropdown.
Now when we `127.0.0.1:XXXX/?selected_facility=4` in the url, it is working fine.

But can we do a small change here. Whenever the user changes the dropdown, the url itself should be get changed to respective once

For example,
When user selects 4, the url should become `127.0.0.1:XXXX/?selected_facility=4`
Similarly, 5, the url should become `127.0.0.1:XXXX/?selected_facility=5`

Right now, the url is not getting changed

```
library(shiny)

facilities <- seq(1:5)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput("selected_facility", "Select facility", choices = facilities)
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observe({
       
        #Get URL query
        query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
        
        #Ignore if the URL query is null
        if (!is.null(query[['selected_facility']])) {

            #Update the select input
            updateSelectInput(session, "selected_facility", selected  = query[['selected_facility']], choices = facilities)
            
        }
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via `updateQueryString`:

```
library(shiny)

facilities <- seq(1:5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selected_facility", "Select facility", choices = facilities)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    #Get URL query
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    #Ignore if the URL query is null
    if (!is.null(query[['selected_facility']])) {
      #Update the select input
      updateSelectInput(session, "selected_facility", selected  = query[['selected_facility']], choices = facilities)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$selected_facility, {
    updateQueryString(
      queryString = sprintf("?selected_facility=%s", input$selected_facility),
      mode = c("replace")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```